# finding vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Consider the plane P in the $x-y-z$ space determined by the equation $x + y + z = 0$.
>   Given the vector $\vec{V} =(2,3,4) $, in default position. Find vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, such that vector $\vec{A}$ lies on the plane $P$, vector $\vec{B}$ is in the same or opposite direction as normal vector to P, and $\vec{V} = \vec{A} + \vec{B}$

Im not sure how to do this question. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please edit the question describing what you have tried, or specifically which concepts you do not understand. Nobody wants to do your homework for you if you haven't put in any effort yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vector lies on the plane then must be orthogonal to a normal vector of the plane $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$.

So we have

$$\langle 1,1,1 \rangle \cdot \langle a_1,a_2,a_3 \rangle=0$$

We have that $\vec B$ is parallel (or equal to) a normal vector of the plane,

$$c \langle 1,1,1 \rangle= \langle b_1,b_2,b_3 \rangle$$

We have $\vec A+\vec B=\vec V$,

$$\langle a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,a_3+b_3 \rangle= \langle 2,3,4 \rangle$$

Combine this information to solve for $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

what you are searching is the [orthogonal decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalDecomposition.html) of the vector $\vec V$ in the spaces $W= span (1,1,1)$ and its orthogonal complement $W^\bot$ ( that is the given plane).

Do you see this?